# CASE and GROUP rows with same values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to group the following 4 rows into 2 rows, by taking all rows with equal `pgroup` and getting an overall GeneralStatus using the `GeneralStatus` of rows with `Unit` 50 or 60.

In the example below, the first 2 rows are a *group*, since both are `GB002` with `pgroup` 1 (Alpha), and they have either `60` or `50`. As you can see, one is ENABLED while the other is DISABLED. So this means that `GB002 Alpha` is DISABLED. In the other example, `GB002` w/ pgroup 3 (Gamma), both rows (`Unit 60 & 50`) are ENABLED, so`GB002 Gamma`is ENABLED.

Basically, the final result should be:

```
GB002,Alpha, DISABLED
GB002,Gamma, ENABLED
```

This is what I've tried, but I can't seem to get it:

```
declare @table table 
(
    ID varchar(10),
    pgroup varchar(5),
    Unit varchar(5),
    GeneralStatus varchar(10)
)

insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'GB002',1, 60, 'ENABLED'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'GB002',1, 50, 'DISABLED'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'GB002',3, 60, 'ENABLED'
insert into @table (id, pgroup, unit, GeneralStatus) select 'GB002',3, 50, 'ENABLED'
--select *From @table

select 
id,
case 
    when pgroup = 1 then 'Alpha'
    when pgroup = 2 then 'Beta'
    when pgroup = 3 then 'Gamma'
END, 
case 
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table t2 
          WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
          AND t1.Unit=t2.Unit
          AND GeneralStatus = 'ENABLED') >= 2 then 'ENABLED'
    ELSE 'DISABLED'
end GeneralStatus
from @table t1  where unit in (60,50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select id, pgroup,
       (case when min(GeneralStatus) = max(GeneralStatus) and
                  max(GeneralStatus) = 'Enabled'
             then 'Enabled'
             else 'Disabled'
        end) as GeneralStatus
from @table t
where unit in (50, 60)
group by id, pgroup;
```

It assigns `Enabled` only when all the status values are `'Enabled'`.

If you know the values are *always* `'Enabled'` and `'Disabled'`, you can use this hack:

```
select id, pgroup, min(GeneralStatus) as GeneralStatus
from @table t
where unit in (50, 60)
group by id, pgroup;
```

Comment: The values will always be the same, so the hack works well. Thanks.